# Given a set of integers $D$ and a positive value$P$, find an algorithm to find set of integers satisfying a condition

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, sets, number-theory, linear-algebra

Given a set of positive integers :

$ \\ D = \{ D_1, D_2, ..., D_n\}$

and a non-negative integer $P$, where $P$ is divisible by every element in $D$, then find a set of non-negative integers:

$C = \{ C_1, C_2,..., C_n\}$

such that

$S > P $

where
$S = \displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^nC_iD_i$
and for all $i$ where $C_i > 0 $,

$\ S - D_i < P$

There can be multiple solutions, any solution can suffice.

For example, if

$D = \{2, 6, 9 \}$
$P = 18$

$ C $ can be:

$C = \{0, 2, 1 \}$

since $ S = 0*2 + 2*6 + 1*9 = 21 > 18 $
and $ 21 - 6 = 15 < 18 $ and $ 21 - 9  = 12 < 18 $

What can be some approaches to tackle this?
For starters, is there a way to ensure that there even exists a solution? There can be examples where there is no solution.

Comment: What approaches have you considered?  What progress have you made so far?

Comment: @D.W. I have tried approaching it by finding 2 integers Ci and Cj such that the condition is satisfied. The result gives that if there are Di and Dj such that Di < Dj and 2*Di > Dj, then we can have Ci  = P/Di - 1 and Cj = 1 rest all zero.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I find that a lot clearer.  I suggest you start by trying to solve the special case $n=2$ first.  Can you do that?  What's the context where you encountered this?  Can you credit the source where you originally saw it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of $D$ divide $P$, then $P$ is also multiple of $\gcd(D)$.
Any sum like $S$ is a multiple of $\gcd(D)$ too, so you can divide everything by $\gcd(D)$ and consider just the case where the $D_i$ are relatively prime. For definiteness, take $D$ sorted in increasing order. 
In that case you have just:

$\begin{equation*}
  P
    = c \cdot \prod_{1 \le k \le n} D_k
\end{equation*}$

For the [Frobenius problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) sums like $S$ with non-negative $C_i$ can represent all numbers greater than a function $g(D)$, and [it can be shown](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Talks/frob6.pdf) that $g(D) < D_n^2$ (computing the exact value of $g(D)$ is NP-complete). So, if $P > D_n^2$ (the other $D_k$ would have to be small indeed for this to be false), any number $S \ge P$ can be represented, and also any number $S - D_i$, pick say $S = P + 1$ to satisfy your condition.

To get a set of $C_i$, you can now use the greedy algorithm: Take $C_n = \lfloor S / D_n \rfloor$ (as large as possible), $S \leftarrow S - C_n D_n$, and repeat for the next largest.